# Add image along the LineString

Tags: openlayers, linestring

I am wondering how to place images on a line. For example, instead of a dotted or dashed line. I could include a symbol of a cloud a character (e.g. |) repeated along the line. it cannot show the image along with line.

```
  var style = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                     opacity: 1,
                     size:20,
                     src: 'https://i.imgsafe.org/73d1273.png'
                     })),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'black',
      width: 4,
      lineDash: [5],
     })
     });
```

I did a lot of research, but I couldn't find any results.
Does it support OpenLayers? How can it be done if it supports it?

Code sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/jguxq4j0/8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will probably need to use a wide stroke with repeating image pattern.  I couldn't find a small cloud symbol or one with a background so I loaded a large one and scaled it down on top of a background, then used the result to create a repeat pattern.

```
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source:  new ol.source.OSM() 
});

var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var tCnv = document.createElement("canvas");
var tCtx = tCnv.getContext("2d");
var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/weather-429/64/weather_icons_color-02-256.png';
img.onload = function(){

  var size = 32;
  tCnv.width = size;
  tCnv.height = size;
  tCtx.rect(0, 0, size, size);
  tCtx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
  tCtx.fill();
  tCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, size, size);

  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(tCnv, 'repeat');

  var style = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: pattern,
      width: size
    })
  });

  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: style
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [-11000000, 4600000],
      zoom: 4
    })
  });

  map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'LineString'
  }));
};
```

Here'a another alternative, based on the function linked in the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577429/markers-in-openlayer-linestring to split a linestring into equal segments.  I've added options to place icons at the midpoints of those segments, or at the segment ends, and the angle is calculated so the icons can be aligned with the stroke, with another option for alwaysUp so rotation is limited to plus or minus 90 degrees, or any angle including downwards can be allowed so arrows, etc. can follow the line as drawn.

```
function splitLineString(geometry, minSegmentLength, options) {

  function calculatePointsDistance(coord1, coord2) {
    var dx = coord1[0] - coord2[0];
    var dy = coord1[1] - coord2[1];
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  };

  function calculateSplitPointCoords(startNode, nextNode, distanceBetweenNodes, distanceToSplitPoint) {
    var d = distanceToSplitPoint / distanceBetweenNodes;
    var x = nextNode[0] + (startNode[0] - nextNode[0]) * d;
    var y = nextNode[1] + (startNode[1] - nextNode[1]) * d;
    return [x, y];
  };

  function calculateAngle(startNode, nextNode, alwaysUp) {
    var x = (startNode[0] - nextNode[0]);
    var y = (startNode[1] - nextNode[1]);
    var angle = Math.atan(x/y);
    if (!alwaysUp) {
       angle = y > 0 ? angle + Math.PI : x < 0 ? angle + Math.PI*2 : angle;
    }
    return angle;
  };

  var splitPoints = [];
  var coords = geometry.getCoordinates();

  var coordIndex = 0;
  var startPoint = coords[coordIndex];
  var nextPoint = coords[coordIndex + 1];
  var angle = calculateAngle(startPoint, nextPoint, options.alwaysUp);

  var n = Math.ceil(geometry.getLength()/minSegmentLength);
  var segmentLength = geometry.getLength() / n;
  var currentSegmentLength = options.midPoints ? segmentLength/2 : segmentLength;

  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

    var distanceBetweenPoints = calculatePointsDistance(startPoint, nextPoint);
    currentSegmentLength += distanceBetweenPoints;

    if (currentSegmentLength < segmentLength) {
      coordIndex++;
      if(coordIndex < coords.length - 1) {
        startPoint = coords[coordIndex];
        nextPoint = coords[coordIndex + 1];
        angle = calculateAngle(startPoint, nextPoint, options.alwaysUp);
        i--;
        continue;
      } else {
        if (!options.midPoints) {
          var splitPointCoords = nextPoint;
          if (!options.extent || ol.extent.containsCoordinate(options.extent, splitPointCoords)) {
            splitPointCoords.push(angle);
            splitPoints.push(splitPointCoords);
          }
        }
        break;
      }
    } else {
      var distanceToSplitPoint = currentSegmentLength - segmentLength;
      var splitPointCoords = calculateSplitPointCoords(startPoint, nextPoint, distanceBetweenPoints, distanceToSplitPoint);
      startPoint = splitPointCoords.slice();
      if (!options.extent || ol.extent.containsCoordinate(options.extent, splitPointCoords)) {
        splitPointCoords.push(angle);
        splitPoints.push(splitPointCoords);
      }
      currentSegmentLength = 0;
    }
  }

  return splitPoints;
};


var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source:  new ol.source.OSM() 
});

var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var style = function(feature, resolution) {

  var size = 32;

  var styles = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
        width: size
      })
  })];

  var mapSize = map.getSize();
  var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent([mapSize[0] + (size*2), mapSize[1] + (size*2)]);

  var splitPoints = splitLineString(feature.getGeometry(),size * resolution, {alwaysUp: true, midPoints: true, extent: extent});
  splitPoints.forEach( function(point) {

    styles.push(new ol.style.Style({
      geometry: new ol.geom.Point([point[0],point[1]]),
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        src: 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/weather-429/64/weather_icons_color-02-256.png',
        scale: 0.125,
        rotation: point[2]
      })
    }));

  });

  return styles;
}

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  style: style
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 4
  })
});

map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: source,
  type: 'LineString'
}));
```

http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/linestring-stroke.html

http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/linestring-icons-1.html

http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/linestring-icons-2.html

This two stage setup keeps the number of passes through the loop below 1 million, which would typically be reached at level 16 or 17 with an intercontinental linestring, and can zoom to level 28 before reaching that load again.  For accuracy in the second stage the linestring vertices must be included in the first stage results, but unnecessary calculations such as angle can be omitted.

```
function splitLineString(geometry, minSegmentLength, options) {

  function calculatePointsDistance(coord1, coord2) {
    var dx = coord1[0] - coord2[0];
    var dy = coord1[1] - coord2[1];
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  };

  function calculateSplitPointCoords(startNode, nextNode, distanceBetweenNodes, distanceToSplitPoint) {
    var d = distanceToSplitPoint / distanceBetweenNodes;
    var x = nextNode[0] + (startNode[0] - nextNode[0]) * d;
    var y = nextNode[1] + (startNode[1] - nextNode[1]) * d;
    return [x, y];
  };

  function calculateAngle(startNode, nextNode, alwaysUp) {
    var x = (startNode[0] - nextNode[0]);
    var y = (startNode[1] - nextNode[1]);
    var angle = Math.atan(x/y);
    if (!alwaysUp) {
       angle = y > 0 ? angle + Math.PI : x < 0 ? angle + Math.PI*2 : angle;
    }
    return angle;
  };

  var splitPoints = [];
  var coords = geometry.getCoordinates();

  var coordIndex = 0;
  var startPoint = coords[coordIndex];
  var nextPoint = coords[coordIndex + 1];
  var angle = options.vertices || calculateAngle(startPoint, nextPoint, options.alwaysUp);

  var n = Math.ceil(geometry.getLength()/minSegmentLength);
  var segmentLength = geometry.getLength() / n;
  var midPoints = (options.midPoints && !options.vertices)
  var currentSegmentLength = midPoints ? segmentLength/2 : segmentLength;

  console.log(n);

  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

    var distanceBetweenPoints = calculatePointsDistance(startPoint, nextPoint);
    currentSegmentLength += distanceBetweenPoints;

    if (currentSegmentLength < segmentLength) {
      coordIndex++;
      if(coordIndex < coords.length - 1) {
        startPoint = coords[coordIndex];
        nextPoint = coords[coordIndex + 1];
        angle = options.vertices || calculateAngle(startPoint, nextPoint, options.alwaysUp);
        if (options.vertices && (!options.extent || ol.extent.containsCoordinate(options.extent, startPoint))) {
          splitPoints.push(startPoint);
        }
        i--;
        continue;
      } else {
        if (!midPoints) {
          var splitPointCoords = nextPoint;
          if (!options.extent || ol.extent.containsCoordinate(options.extent, splitPointCoords)) {
            if (!options.vertices) { splitPointCoords.push(angle); }
            splitPoints.push(splitPointCoords);
          }
        }
        break;
      }
    } else {
      var distanceToSplitPoint = currentSegmentLength - segmentLength;
      var splitPointCoords = calculateSplitPointCoords(startPoint, nextPoint, distanceBetweenPoints, distanceToSplitPoint);
      startPoint = splitPointCoords.slice();
      if (!options.extent || ol.extent.containsCoordinate(options.extent, splitPointCoords)) {
        if (!options.vertices) { splitPointCoords.push(angle); }
        splitPoints.push(splitPointCoords);
      }
      currentSegmentLength = 0;
    }
  }

  return splitPoints;
};

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source:  new ol.source.OSM() 
});

var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var style = function(feature, resolution) {

  var size = 32;

  var styles = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
        width: size
      })
  })];

  console.log('zoom=' + map.getView().getZoom());

  var mapSize = map.getSize();
  var geom = feature.getGeometry();
  var n = geom.getLength() / (size * resolution);

  if (n > 1000000) {
     n = Math.sqrt(n/100);
     var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent([mapSize[0] * n, mapSize[1] * n]);
     var splitPoints = splitLineString(geom, size * resolution * n, {extent: extent, vertices: true});
     var geom = new ol.geom.LineString(splitPoints);
  }

  var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent([mapSize[0] + (size*2), mapSize[1] + (size*2)]);

  var splitPoints = splitLineString(geom, size * resolution, {alwaysUp: true, midPoints: true, extent: extent});
  splitPoints.forEach( function(point) {

    styles.push(new ol.style.Style({
      geometry: new ol.geom.Point([point[0],point[1]]),
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        src: 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/weather-429/64/weather_icons_color-02-256.png',
        scale: 0.125,
        rotation: point[2]
      })
    }));

  });

  return styles;
}
```

Unless you include vertices in the first stage sections of the linestring won't  be in the extent for the next stage.

[image]

Comment: So how can I add this stroke rotation feature?

Comment: A very nice code, but because it calculates too many points when it is too close to the map, it gives a memory error and the page closes. Every time I tried to avoid calculating it, but I failed. What can I do for this memory error?

Comment: Yes, when zooming in on a long linestring it calculates more and closer points to keep the spacing equal on the screen, but it does that for the whole linestring not just the visible part, and sets a style for each which eats memory.  It's going to need some refinement to only set styles for points which will be visible in the frame.

Comment: To solve this problem, I tried to enlarge the picture as the zoom increased and I tried to reduce the number of accounts but it is not working as a solution right now.

Comment: I've added a check that the icon position is in (or overlaps the edge of) the visible extent before including it's style

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. That was the control I wanted to do.

Comment: It's more efficient if the extent is passed to the splitLineString function so unnecessary coordinates are never added to the returned coordinate array.

Comment: Yes, for example, when I drew a line from America to Russia, and I set the rapprochement level 22, the browser was closing. The current state is more useful, but there is still the same problem. My idea is that the best solution for this is that the cycle does not work unnecessarily. Because when I look in the debug mode, over 20 million cycles are running and this is pushing the processor.

Comment: Although the memory issue seems to be resolved zooming an intercontinental line down to building level is still very slow due to the number of calculations.  If you are expecting extreme cases such as that it would be better use multiple passes, first calling splitLineString with a larger minSegmentLength and an extent 2 or 3 times bigger than the viewport to find the sections which might be of interest, then calling it again to refine just those parts.

Comment: The code you shared with last is very successful in terms of performance, but when you do a bit too much drawing and zoom, the value is equal to undefined and the code doesn't work. I shared the sample code and if you try and draw a little, it will give an error. I tried to correct this, but I couldn't find out why the value came undefined. Sample code as below:
http://jsfiddle.net/jguxq4j0/13/

Comment: I understand why you made the mistake. But I couldn't find any method for solution.
if (! options.extent || ol.extent.containsCoordinate (options.extent, splitPointCoords))
The method returns false, and because splitPoints has not expired, the coordinate does not return to the geometry at the next stage and returns an error. I don't understand why he doesn't get these limits true.

Comment: vertices must be set true in the first stage, otherwise you will omit part of the string

Comment: When I add this condition, the code does not fail, but it works very slowly again. I don't understand why these values are sometimes missing?

                if(splitPoints.length!=0){
                    var geom = new ol.geom.LineString(splitPoints);
                }

Comment: Dude, I'm sorry I asked too many questions, thank you for all your help with this job. I took a look at the picture you took yesterday. If the n> 1000000 requirement is met, the intersection is changing and the line slips to another place, which is a bad result. How can I solve this? If I remove n> 1000000, it gives an error after a certain operation. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: The only way to stop it is to include the vertices in the first stage.  You could experiment with `n = Math.sqrt(n/100)` maybe a smaller or larger extent such as `Math.sqrt(n/1000)` or `Math.sqrt(n/10)` could give better performance in some cases by changing the balance between the two stages.

Comment: Thank you for your information. If I find any solution I will share.